# PHP - Generating pages based on MySQL queries

Tags: php, mysql

I've been writing a small blogging system to advance my knowledge of PHP, and I'm having fun writing it. I've been using one page, coupled with jquery's pajinate plugin to display all my blog entries through one page. However, my question here is can I generate a page which displays a blog article with the id of 2?

What I want to do is generate the article, but dump it to a page (content/article-name-here.php). Is there any way of automating the process?

(Sorry if it's not clear)

Comment: Do you actually want a file to be generated, or just the appearance of a file? The latter is the preferred method and one of the awesome capabilities of PHP coupled with mod_rewrite.

Comment: Recommendations. 1) Don't aim to have ".php" in the title. Go for extensionless URLs. mod_rewrite is a really easy tool that will let you do this. 2) Rather than using the id, have a unique index on a slug on the database, i.e. 'article-name-here'

Comment: I have a simple rewrite system in place already :D

Comment: @Sohnee just for got record, mod_rewrite can handle extensions too, so you can make a URL conform to this.php, that.html, something.jsp or nothing.aspx, and redirect to whatever you want.

Comment: @ChrisSobolewski - my point was to avoid extensions. Why does a visitor have to care whether the site is .php, .html, .anything. Extensionless URLs are far preferable.

Comment: @Sohnee And to add to that, extensionless URLs are a "security through obscurity" measure which makes a hackers job just a little more difficult since they don't immediately know what server side language you are using.

Comment: @cillosis - good point - although you would have to change the response headers too to remove "Powered by PHP"! The main concern of all things "The Web" ought to be real people who visit your website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a basic SQL query:

```
SELECT * FROM blogEntries WHERE id=2
```

(Note: Never use SELECT * unless you're actually using all the data)

I have done the same project as you, creating a simple blogging engine, and I use the same page for both the general list and the single article.

Using a URL such as `example.com/?blogId=2` you can modify your query:

```
$SQL = 'SELECT * FROM blogEntries';
//if $_GET['id'] has a value, append it to query
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $SQL .= 'WHERE id=' . $_GET['blogId'];
};
//Execute SQL Query
//process your data as you want it to appear
```

If you want custom URLs for each blog entry, you will want to look in to Mod_Rewrite:
http://www.workingwith.me.uk/articles/scripting/mod_rewrite

Comment: You shouldn't use `SELECT *` even if you are using all the fields (or so I've heard).

Comment: The argument against SELECT * if you are NOT using all the fields is performance based. The argument against using it if you ARE going to use all the fields is based on maintaining the code, AFAIK.